# BizTalk: Analyze binary blob hiding in XmlDocument?

Tags: stream, blob, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm using BizTalk 2013 R1 to download a binary blob from a website via http. When I receive the blob, I'm just storing the message in an XmlDocument. However, sometimes that site returns the files I want, and sometimes it returns errors in the form of http pages containing error information.

I've attempted to screen for this by trying to run xpath on my return message. In particular, I'm looking for occurrences of "Error" in /html/head/title. My thinking is that if it find that text, or if it parses as Xml at all, I've gotten an error and I should throw an exception.

In practice though, I get this when I attempt to run that xpath:

```
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 128.30.52.100:80
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenAndPush(Uri uri)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.PushExternalEntityOrSubset(String publicId, String systemId, Uri baseUri, String entityName)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy_PushExternalSubset(String systemId, String publicId)
   at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseExternalSubset()
   at System.Xml.DtdParser.Parse(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
   at System.Xml.DtdParser.System.Xml.IDtdParser.ParseInternalDtd(IDtdParserAdapter adapter, Boolean saveInternalSubset)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDtd()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(TextReader txtReader)
   at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Value.GetXmlDocument()
   at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Value.RetrieveAs(Type t)
   at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Part.get_XmlDocument()
   at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Part.XPathLoad(Part sourcePart, String xpath, Type dstType)
   at QTC.BizTalk.LSPDispatchIMNL.SendCommercialInvoice.segment3(StopConditions stopOn)
   at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment s, StopConditions stopCond, Exception& exp)
```

Upon seeing this, it makes sense since I believe that BizTalk handles messages as streams in the background. Suddenly, the technique of hiding binary in XmlDocuments makes sense. So perhaps my test itself is causing a different problem.

I would like to be able to validate my response in some way, however. Is there anything I can do to analyze the response I get from the site, without causing the message to load? There's nothing all that useful in the context properties so I'm curious what I can do.

Comment: Can't you rely on the HTTP status code of the download response to identify errors?

Comment: I presume you are doing this in an orchestration? What approach are you taking to call the web service? Request via send port or expression shape? Is it a RESTful service you are requesting data from?

Comment: @Gruff This is being done within an orchestration, yes. It's configured to use a send port, and the send port is using BizTalk 2013 WCF-WebHttp to interact with a REST service.

Comment: @Filburt Sadly, when viewing the message in tracked messages, it seems that even when the service returns an error page, the InboundHttpStatusCode and InboundHttpStatusDescription context properties are both "OK" despite the return message being packed with error information.

Comment: Maybe a response length/message size threshold to distinguish between data and error messages?

Comment: @Filburt I had considered that! Our typical payload is about 70k while the error response is 7k. Is the message size available in context somewhere? Do you know if it's possible to get it without causing the message to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure how to make sense of your error (especially without seeing the code you're actually using to check the message), but either way I think you should do this in a custom pipeline component, for a few reasons.

1. Loading the XmlDocument into the orchestration is going to be prohibitive if you're dealing with large binary objects.
2. Trying to use XPath on binary data won't work
3. Trying to use XPath on HTML won't always work

You could very easily check the message size in a pipeline component (`pInMsg.BodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream().Length` for example).  You could also try to read the first few bytes of the stream and check those for certain conditions more efficiently.

Comment: Agreed, my approach had been to attempt the xpath within a handled scope, expecting an exception when trying to treat the binary as html. I did also observe your third claim in which xpath on html doesn't work, however I'm not in love with my approach anyway so I'm excited to try other solutions.

Comment: I agree with the answer here. I generally would recommend to do this in a pipeline for the same reasons. Any preprocessing you can do in a custom pipeline component (that's what it's for).

Comment: I tried this approach and it worked, but for future viewers of the this thread, I also managed to accomplish the same thing by accessing the WCF.InboundHttpHeaders context property since WCF-WebHttp populates it for me. In this case, I was able to carve out not only the Content-Length header, but also the more useful Content-Type, so that I could detect 'text/html' and throw errors if so.